# json data to textview

Tags: android, json

I am pulling my data from a database and I am using json. What methods should I use in order to print them on texview items of my xml file, because I am little bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the JSON already wrapped as an java Object, then you can do this to get the textview in your Actvity and set your text:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
text.setText("My JSON text");
```

myTextView should be the ID fof your textview in your XML layout.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if your JSONObject is "js"

```
TextView tx= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tx);
tx.setText(js.getString("somefield"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textView.setText(string)
```

will allow you to put the text into the text view. As we don't know if you were able to extract the needed item or you want to display the full json string, we can't help more.